A short fiction about aliens able to determine the "qualitative" colour of distant planets and only discover spectroscopy later
This short fiction (short story or maybe novelette, I am not sure) I read less than 10 years ago but I don't remember exactly when. I don't remember where but since I rarely read magazines it was probably in some collection.
There were aliens who had so efficient telescopes they could determine the colours of planets in stellar systems far from theirs. But since they did not have spectroscopes these colours were just qualitative. But they believed that each colour (and they had many nuances for each of our six main colours, and more) was the signature of a given type of planet.
But then they developed precise spectroscopy, I mean, the study of spectral lines. And they noticed that though the spectral lines of all planets having a given colour were indeed almost identical, one planet was very special. Instead of showing the same spectral lines as the other planets of the same "qualitative" colour, the lines were very different. So they came to investigate this bizarre planet. And they did not like what they saw, and IIRC, they just wiped out all life on this anomaly which was Earth..

Bears a vague resemblance to Marion Zimmer Bradley's Colors of Space where the protagonist is a human with an extended color vision capability who can see the color of the space travel monopoly fuel that the antagonist aliens (Lhari), who have no(?) color vision, use spectroscopy to find and have only seen it in their galaxy The protagonist realizes he saw the color on a planet in our galaxy...

@bob1  I read the synopsis on Wikipedia. It is not my story.  It is a novel, not a short fiction. And it is not a "first contact", humans did have access to space travel, even if only limited by the Lhari monopoly, but are Earth bound in my story. Also the aliens (Lhari) have no colour vision and use spectroscopy and in mine they have an excellent colour vision and discover spectroscopy only shortly before the events of the story. Thanks anyway !

Thanks, knew it was a very long shot - hence not an answer.
